# DataSource.Table.Where(stringOfConstraint) does not exist in LinqToSQL for OData support?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm looking at [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/clientbinding/defaultcs.aspx) Telerik demo, and am unable to get the "count" statement to work.  I believe that the following command is only supported on EntityFramework, and not Linq2SQL.

```
return  CurrentDataSource.Products.Where(where).Count();
```

The parameter "where" in lowercase is actually a string that is passed in the ADO.Net DataServices (OData) url.  This URL *should* be sent to the Linq provider to further constrain the query.

If that is not supported in Linq2SQL, how can I make a similar statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a lambda expression for the predicate used by the `Queryable.Where` method:

```
return CurrentDataSource.Products.Where(p => p.Id > 100).Count();
```

If you really want to use a string then take a look at Dynamic LINQ, starting with Scott Gu's blog post: [Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). Then you should be able to write queries similar to:

```
return CurrentDataSource.Products.Where("Id > 100").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own generic extension, how you should write the most effective one depends on the situation... but it should probably be something like:

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions 
{
    public static int Count(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
       return query.ToList().Count;
    }
}
```

This is probably not the most effective way and only works if you have an IQueryable. If performance is not a problem just use it.